# Java Program error with JBoss upgrade to 7

Tags: java, jboss7.x, jdeveloper

Our application server was recently upgraded to version 7 of JBoss and since then I am unable to connect through the development tool JDeveloper.  The desktop application has two projects, one for the Models and one for the functionality.  I am getting the error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory.  Anyone have any ideas?  I can provide any information required.

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+AS7 , in the chapter 'Update application JNDI namespace names'?

Comment: I looked over that doc and, unfortunately, am even more lost.  Major problem is that I am not only new to Java but brand new to JBoss, JDeveloper and everything else that is involved.  I inherited a project that was and is functioning just fine installed on PC around the office.  But when I try to run it in the IDE, I get those errors.  It is strange that the applicaiton does not fail but it does in the IDE.

Comment: @StephaneM Here's the situation - they have upgraded the server to JBoss 7 but are still running JBoss 6.  The app I am examining has been installed on my PC as an EXE and runs nicely.  They tried to execute the beans in JBoss 7 but got a bunch of errors.  At the same time, they installed JBoss 7 on my PC.  Could this installation on my PC be the problem I am having?  If I uninstall it shouldn't it connect the same way that the EXE does?  All of my problems began when they installed JBoss 7 on my PC and on the server.